# Join only subset of columns with sqlalchemy core

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a clean way to join two tables but only select a subset of the joined table's columns?

e.g.

`join_query = table_a.join(table_b, columns=[table_b.c.column_a, table_b.c.column_b])`

I'm trying to avoid using `select` since I would have to list dozens of needed columns from table_a, but I want only a couple columns from column b.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the way to do it, `select` can take either specific columns or full table references as args, so the answer would be

`join_query = table_a.join(table_b).select(table_a, table_b.c.column_a, table_b.column_b)`

Comment: That code doesn't work, did you mean `join_query = select(table_a, table_b.c.column_a, table_b.c.column_b).join(table_b)`?